# Android NDK develop method

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'd like to make a library for Android with C++.
Normally there is no problem with function calls via JNI.
However, there will be many approaching if both Android(app) and C++(library) need same class(or data structure) definition.

What is the best approaching?
Is there any reference or example?

Comment: have some advices: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jni/index.html